# how can I change the setting for number of upload retries in the IDE?

Tags: arduino-ide, avrdude

I run into this problem when I mess something up, and it's pretty annoying to wait for 10 not in sync timeouts before I can try some different method.

```
...
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 9 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x85
```

How can I set the number of "attempts" to say 2 instead of 10? Or how can I safely interrupt the upload process in the IDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is not in the arduino ide but in the tool chain (.exe) that it runs.

Normally it is a program called avrdude.exe that is running so you would need to rebuild the avrdude.exe tool which is not practical.

The easiest way, but rather crude, is to pull the usb cable. If the port disappears avrdude should stop immediately.

Comment: what's the harder proper way?